# Airflow query to get dag failures, after exhausting retries

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to query the Airflow meta database to get dagrun failures.

We have dags with multiple tasks. Each task is scheduled to retry 3 times. After 3x the dag fails and sends an email.

- If it fails and succeeds on the retries, the dag succeeds. We **don't** want to list these.
- If it fails and still fails on retries, the dag fails. We typically make a fix and then reset the same dagrun execution and the dagrun succeeds. We **want** to identify these.

I think the meta database shows this dag_run as `state=Success`.

Is it possible to identify failed dagruns if I've marked dagruns as success?

v2.2.5

edit: or is there a way to check if airflow sent a failure email?

Comment: you can add a note manually and then find if the dag_run has this note. its a good practice to document what you fix/did for this dag_run neither way

Comment: I see, this is only on v2.5+. We're on v2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

You can check if "Data interval start" is different from "Queued at".

in case of sceduling its the same time, but if you clear all tasks (re-run dag) then the "Queued at" will be the time you re-run the dag

in case of scheduling :

[image]

after re-run

[image]